# How to make component stick to bottom in ScrollView but still alow other content to push it down

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have three views:  one at the top, middle and bottom. The scroll view takes the whole screen. The problem is that now scroll view is not scrollable.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#00ff00', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <View><SomeContent /></View>
  <View><SomeContent /></View>
  <View><SomeContent /></View>
</ScrollView>
```

If I remove `flex: 1` scroll view takes about 50% of the screen. 
How do I make a scroll view with top, middle and bottom elements like on the image bellow.

[image: Screenshot of an iPhone. The background of the screen is white. It has three boxes that are different shades of blue: one at the top, one in the middle, and one at bottom. The boxes are aligned to the left and there is a lot of white space between the boxes.]

The bottom element should be at the bottom all the time but when the top two components' height is large they should push the bottom component down so I can use scroll view to move up/down.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use flexGrow instead of flex. Example code is given bellow.

```
<ScrollView 
  contentContainerStyle={{ 
  flexGrow: 1, 
  flexDirection: 'column', 
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
}}>
  <View style={{ width: 50, height: 1000, backgroundColor:'orange' }} />
  <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'black'}} />
  <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor:'blue'}} />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: [1]]

Comment: Are you able to indicate why flexGrow helps in this case?

Comment: after spending 3 days without no hope, this info saved me from getting crazy.

Answer (score 14):

By removing flex: 1, you are seeing only the exact height for the Views.

```
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00ff00', 
      flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#b0e0e6' }} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#87ceeb'}} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#4682b4'}} />
  </ScrollView>
```

[image: no flex]

If you set flex: 1 or flexGrow: 1, ScrollView will set the min height to the height of the screen.

```
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#00ff00', 
      flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#b0e0e6' }} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#87ceeb'}} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#4682b4'}} />
  </ScrollView>
```

[image: outer flex]

If the cumulative height of the Views is greater than this, the overall view will extend beyond the height of the screen.  In this case, **flexGrow: 1** (shown partially scrolled below), will let you scroll to the content, but flex: 1 will cut it off.

```
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: '#00ff00', 
      flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 700, backgroundColor:'#b0e0e6' }} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#87ceeb'}} />
    <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#4682b4'}} />
  </ScrollView>
```

[image: scrolled flexGrow]

From there, you can set flex on each of the Views to weight how the blank space will be filled by the Views.  For example, if you set flex: 1 on each of the top two Views, and flex: 2 on the bottom View, then *after* accounting for the content height, the bottom view will be given 1/2 of the overall height to 1/4 for each of the top two Views.  Like this:

```
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: '#00ff00', 
      flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#b0e0e6' }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#87ceeb'}} />
    <View style={{ flex: 2, width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor:'#4682b4'}} />
  </ScrollView>
```

[image: inner flex]

ScrollView documentation:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html