# Align Button to Bottom in ScrollView

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to align a button to bottom of the ScrollView and make the ScrollView fill the page. First screenshot is how it looks like and the second one is what I want.

[image: Current Status]

[image: What I want]

In the screenshots, ScrollView is not used since there aren't enough items but number of items inside of the ScrollView is not fixed.

Render():

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text style={styles.bigTitle}>Title</Text>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <SignupButton onPress={this.submit} title="Next Step" image={require("../Images/right_btn.png")} boldText={true} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Style:

```
  scrollViewContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  formContainer: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 50,
    paddingRight: 50,
    paddingBottom: 30,
  },
  bigTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
```

Comment: For clarity, if the form _were_ to be large enough to scroll do you want the button always fixed, or to scroll with the content?

Comment: No it shouldn't be fixed. It should be at the end of the scroll.

Comment: FYI: You can use `contentContainerStyle` to remove that inner wrapping `View`. [See docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle)

Comment: try using contentContainerStyle={{ flex:1 }} in scrollview

Comment: What is **Style** block?  Is that CSS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check my answer on similar question. Here is the link.

[How to make component stick to bottom in ScrollView but still alow other content to push it down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806193/how-to-make-component-stick-to-bottom-in-scrollview-but-still-alow-other-content/44516125#44516125)

Comment: Thank you, using `flexGrow` fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `justifyContent:'space-between'` and `flex:1` to contentContainerStyle to ScrollView

```
  <ScrollView style={style.container} contentContainerStyle={[{flex:1,justifyContent:'space-between'}]} >
    <LIST />
    <Button />
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go just take it out of the ScrollView and make sure that it's at the bottom, if your parent is Relative`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
to your SignUpbutton, if it's a LinearLayout make sure this is the last View in the xml and that the LinearLayout's height is filling the screen, If it's FrameLayout then I believe you need to use gravity set to bottom :)

```
<SomeLayout>
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text style={styles.bigTitle}>Title</Text>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
        <SignupButton onPress={this.submit} title="Next Step" image={require("../Images/right_btn.png")} boldText={true} />
</SomeLayout>
```

SomeLayout is a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout or any other Layout your using...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this time the button always will be visible at the bottom. What I want for button is to be at the end of the ScrollView.