# Align child in ScrollView to Bottom or scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I was having the same problem discussed over here [Align Button to Bottom in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656712/align-button-to-bottom-in-scrollview) but with native Android.

Imagine you have following layout:

[image: Content smaller than height]

As the content might not fit on smaller screens/configurations you wrap your content in a scrollview.
Plus: To avoid that users miss critical content which is below the fold you want that the CTA is positioned below the content.

| Screen | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | ScrollView: - ConstraintLayout -- //content -- Button |

But now the CTA is not aligned to the bottom of the screen anymore.
For taller devices where no scrolling is necessary it would look like this:

[image]

*How can we get the button still be positioned on the bottom when the content is not scrolling?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple to achieve that:

Make your `ScrollView` grow the whole screen by using `android:fillViewport="true"`
This will stretch the child (ConstraintLayout) to fill the whole screen if it is smaller.

[image]

Now that the child of the scrollview is full-height, you can align the CTA to the bottom of it's parent

| Screen | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | ScrollView: - ConstraintLayout -- //content -- Button(toBottomOf=parent) |

And if the content scrolls, the button will still align below it.

Comment: Your answer is good and it helped me. However, it is not detailed enough technically. I had a problem aligning the CTA to the bottom, while also preventing it from being overlapped by the content. If I only align it to the bottom, it will be overlapped with the content above. If I align it to both the bottom and the content, then it will stay in the middle. The key attribute here was setting `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"`, so that it will be fully biased towards the bottom, while still having the top constraints against the content.